# Should I flood the homepage of the site with these questions?

Tags: discussion

Similar to this question, [Does the royal family know about the Wizarding World?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76464/does-the-royal-family-know-about-the-wizarding-world)

Should I flood the homepage of the site with these questions:

Does the [head of state] of [country] know about the Wizarding World? There are 200+ countries.

If not, why not? Point me towards site rules which prohibit this.

Comment: At this point you'd be hard-pressed to show (based on the comments from that thread as Richard mentioned) that your intent is *not* malicious... And malice is probably against the rules. That being said, at no point was it said that posting such questions in and of themselves was *against the rules*; you're completely imagining a plight, there.

Comment: Do it and I'll ask a "Which heads of state know about the Wizarding World?" question that they can all be closed as dupes of.  Without meaning to be rude: for a ~20k user you really should know better.

Comment: @Sachin You're clearly being facetious. That's ok, because you have a concern regarding that question. But rather than take the other side and say "Well if *you* get to ask these questions then so do *I*!", if you have a real concern about that question's validity, then you should have raised a meta question to discuss it.

Comment: @DarthSatan Or clean-up this one to not be so specific such that it covers other heads of state.

Comment: For reference, there was a [similar squabble some time back](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52369) about lightsaber colours in Star Wars.

Comment: @DarthSatan - there are squabbles like that all the time. At at least one of them, it was this user's question serving as ridicule fodder, for that matter.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On the face of it, your plan falls foul of a variety of site rules (per the [FAQ](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help))

- [Be Nice](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) - you're not being nice. You're being smug.
- [Don't be a jerk](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) - You're being a jerk
- [There is no actual problem to be solved](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) - you're not trying to solve a problem, you're trying to make a point.
- [Your question is just a rant in disguise](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) - Self-explanatory